# Dispatch Global Queue Crash

Tags: xcode, multithreading, queue

So, I have an app that does a bunch of math but it ONLY crashes when I use the Global Dispatch Queue to multi-thread.  I think I may be doing them wrong.  Can anyone explain why this is causing a crash?  Or at least how I may try to debug it.

If I do it like this, it prints out the answer fine.  I have looked through the code with instruments and it has no leaks or anything.

```
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSError *error;

//Read in data file
NSString *Data1FileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data1" ofType:@"txt"] usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
NSMutableArray *strides = [[Data1FileContent componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] mutableCopy];

//Read in data file
NSString *Data2FileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data2" ofType:@"txt"] usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
NSMutableArray *gaitTimes = [[Data2FileContent componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] mutableCopy];

//Math
NSMutableArray *result = [gaitlyapunov gaitlyapunov:strides withTimeSteps:gaitTimes withFreq:150 withSegmentApproach:@"strides"];

NSLog(@"result = %@", result);

[gaitTimes release];
[strides release];

});
```

However, when I try to update a UILabel within the code, it causes a crash.

Error:

```
(lldb) //Thrown randomly in the math
```

Code That Causes Issues:

```
//Create a queue
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

    //This prints out fine
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        statusText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"processing..."];
    });


NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSError *error;

//Read data
NSString *Data1FileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data1" ofType:@"txt"] usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
NSMutableArray *strides = [[Data1FileContent componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] mutableCopy];

//Read data
NSString *Data2FileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data2" ofType:@"txt"] usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
NSMutableArray *gaitTimes = [[Data2FileContent componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] mutableCopy];

//Math, that causes crash in this code only
NSMutableArray *result = [gaitlyapunov gaitlyapunov:strides withTimeSteps:gaitTimes withFreq:150 withSegmentApproach:@"strides"];

    //This should print the result into the label
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            statusText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"result: %@", result];
    });

[gaitTimes release];
[strides release];

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked my issue down to a non-thread safe programming issue.  For more information see here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html.